# How to include headers in an ajax post request to web api

Tags: ajax, post, header, http-headers

Hey guys I am having an issue I am a little confused with as I am new to dealing with Web API's.  I am trying to run a POST from an html page to my web api to create a user.  In the post method though it checks for authentication based on headers of the users id.  How would I go about including a header when I send my ajax post.  Right now I am getting the forbidden status response, so I know the ajax is actually hitting the method.

Here is my ajax post call:

```
$(function () {
            var $users = $("#users");
            $("#postForm").submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                var $form = $(this),
                    firstName = $form.find("input[name='firstName']").val(),
                    lastName = $form.find("input[name='lastName']").val(),
                    email = $form.find("input[name='email']").val(),
                    password = $form.find("input[name='password']").val(),
                    url = $form.attr("action");

                var posting = $.post(url, { firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, email: email, password: password });

                posting.done(function (data) {
                    var content = $(data).find("#content");
                    $("#result").empty().append(content);
                });

            });
        });
```

and this is my html:

```
form action="http://localhost:24500/api/User" id="postForm">
        <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
        <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        <input type="submit" value="Post User">
    </form>
    <div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use the more flexible .ajax() function. It allows you to specify username and password for basic authentication as configuration parameters.

The documentation - https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/